# tasknumber in MATLAB distributed jobs?

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, distributed-computing, cluster-computing

I'm running a distributed job on a cluster. I need to execute a script that sends me an email when the last task finishes (rather, all the tasks are complete). I have my script ready, but I'm not sure how to go about finding task completion. Is there a task ID analogous to labindex?

The reason I want to build this email feature into the job is so that I can just quit MATLAB after submission and collect my data when it's done. That way I won't waste resources pinging it often to get its state.

Comment: Which scheduler are you using? MathWorks "jobmanager", or something else? (Callbacks in jobmanager rely on MATLAB still executing, so I think you will not be able to use that - other schedulers such as LSF have built-in features to support emailing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
jobMgr = findResource(parameters for your cluster's job manager...);

job = createJob(jobMgr);
set(job, 'JobData', yourdata);
set(job, 'MaximumNumberOfWorkers', yourmaxworkers);
set(job, 'PathDependencies', yourpathdeps);
set(job, 'FileDependencies', yourfiledeps);
set(job, 'Timeout', yourtimeout);

for m = 1:numjobs
   task(m) = createTask(job, @parallelfoo, 1, {m});

   % Calls taskFinish when the task completes
   set(task(m), 'FinishedFcn', {@taskFinish, m});
end
```

Elsewhere, you'll have defined a function taskFinish that gets a callback when each task completes.

```
function taskFinish(taskObj, eventData, tasknum)
   disp(['Task ' num2str(tasknum) ' completed']);
end
```

Note, this code was written for the original release of the Distributed Computing Toolbox (which was subsequently renamed the Parallel Computing Toolbox), so it's possible that there are more elegant ways of accomplishing what you're trying to do.  This gets the job done though, with one caveat -- my understanding is that this callback functionality only works if you're running the MATLAB job manager on your cluster (not one of the third party MPI job managers such as TORQUE).

Comment: This is a little confused. There are two concepts being mixed up here. All PCT tasks look for a function called taskFinish.m and evaluate that in the *worker* after finishing their task; this could be useful to d00b. But the FinishedFcn callbacks only evaluate in the client MATLAB, and require the client MATLAB to still be running. In d00b's situation, s/he wants to quit the client MATLAB before the job finishes, so using FinishedFcn isn't a good idea.

Comment: The OP's rationale for quitting MATLAB was that they didn't want to waste system resources polling to find out if the task is done yet. Polling does not occur here. The taskFinish function is a callback that is triggered by task completion. The "no polling" directive and the "quit Matlab" directive are mutually exclusive. The "quit Matlab" directive requires that you come back later and poll to see if the job is done. My proposed solution honors the "no polling" directive and ignores the "quit Matlab" directive.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this answers much of your question, but you can get at the Task ID when running on the workers like so:

```
t = getCurrentTask();
tid = t.ID;
```

However, note that most schedulers execute tasks in an arbitrary order...

Comment: Thanks for the tip on getting the ID. But if tasks are executed in an arbitrary order, is there anyway to know when all tasks are complete? I don't know what scheduler the cluster uses, as I invoke it with it's own scheduler wrapper function. It looks like matlab's jobmanager though (it's Cornell's Teragrid, so if you happen to know what they use, it'll be helpful).

Comment: My aim is to send an email (they have a wrapper function for that) when all tasks are complete so that I can go get my job results. So far I've just included a flag in my final task definition that tells my function to send an email. But if, as you say, tasks are executed arbitrarily, then this is probably a bad idea.